# How to design a client server architect

Tags: c++, architecture, trading, fix-protocol

I like to know the server (TCP based) architecture to support large scale of clients(at least10K) to implement Fix server. My points are
How we design it.
How to listen on the open port? Use select or poll or any other function.
How to process the response of the client? On large scale we cannot create the one thread for each client.
Should the processing of response is in the different executable and share the request and response to the server executable through IPC.
There is much more on it. I would appreciate if anyone explains it or provide any link.
Thanks

Comment: Did you check the threading structure used in the quickfix library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture depends on what you want to do with the clients incoming data. My guess is that for every incoming message you would perform some computations and probably also return a response.

In that case I would create 1 main listener thread that receives all the incoming messages (Actually, if your hardware has more than 1 physical network device, I would use a listener thread per device and make sure each one is listening to a specific device).
Get the number of CPUs that you have on your machine and create worker threads for each CPU and bind them each thread to one cpu (Maybe number of working thread should be num_of_cpu-1, to leave an availalbe cpu for the listener and dispatcher).

Each thread has a queue and semaphore, the main listener thread just push the incoming data into those queues. There are many way to perform load balancing (Will talk about it later).

Each working thread just works on the requests given to it, and put the response on another queue that is read by the dispatcher.

The dispatcher - there are 2 options here, use a thread for dispatcher (or thread per network device as for listeners), or have the dispatcher actually be the same thread as the listener.
There is some advantage to put them both on the same thread, since it makes it easier to detect lost socket connection and use the same fds for both reading and writing without thread synchronization. However, it could be that using 2 different threads would give better performance, it need to be tested.

Note about load balancing:
This is a topic of its own.
The simplest thing is to use 1 queue for all working threads, but the problem is that they have to lock in order to pop items and the locking can damage performance. (But you get the most balanced load).

Another quite simple approach would be to have a private queue for every worker and perform round-robin when inserting. After every X cycles check the size of all the queues. If some queues are much larger than others then leave them out for the next X cycles and then recheck them again. This is not the best approach, but a simple one to implement and gives some load balancing while no locking is needed.

By the way - There is a way to implement queue between 2 threads without blocking - but this is also another topic.

I hope it helps,
Guy

Comment: Nir, thank for the information. I t would be good if also write something on "here is a way to implement queue between 2 threads without blocking"

Comment: I will, I need some time to organize the code I have, will try to do it in the next few days.

Comment: This is not my code, and I must say that I haven't checked it myself, but I saw this link posted by someone else on this forum for another question: http://www.liblfds.org/ It should include queue, stack and some other data structures that are lock-free

Answer (score 2):

An excellent resource for information on this topic is [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). Although the dimensions there seem a little old, the techniques are still applicable today.

Answer (score 0):

If the client and server are on a secure network then the security aspect is to be minimal - to the extent that the transfers are encrypted. If the clients and the server are not on a secure network - you first want the server and client to authenticate each other and then initiate encrypted data transfer. For data transfer, server-side authentication should suffice. At the end of this authentication use the session key to generate encrypted data stream (symmetric). consider using TFTP it is simple to implement and scales reasonably well.